# How do I make a node move at a certain position?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

In my game, the player gets tapped to move across the screen. However, I have it set up so that it should move like this in my update() func:

```
 if player.position.x == 40 {
   let up = SKAction.moveByX(0,y: 400, duration: 1.0)
    player.runAction(up)
     }
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to make my player move up or down when it hits a certain point? Will post more code if necessary.

Comment: Why is it in Update method? - Try to move it to the touchesBegan method
While it is in update method you are calling the action about 60 times per second.

Comment: I really have no idea. I just thought it would work. But it doesn't want to work in my touchesBegan func either

Comment: moveByY isn't a thing, i have it set so that it'll move by Y by setting the X coordinate to 0

Comment: Oops yes my Bad :) I got confused with moveToY :)

Comment: Okay well I'm still really lost

Comment: Okay lets see, I see that the action is inside the if statement, please ensure it is called - pit a breakpoint or an NSLog there because the code looks proper

Comment: Okay its actually not working. I set up a print("") in my conditional and its not being called.

Comment: Then to ensure that the action code is right I would suggest to change == to != and see if the player is moving :-)

Comment: Yep it works with that.

Comment: Glad it works ;-) - Just change your if staement accrodingly to what you need and I still suggest to move this away from the update - to avoid performance issues

Comment: Oh okay now i get it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a range of x values and then use your action. Using == 40 is not that great an option because the position is rarely ever exactly 40.

```
 if player.position.x>39 && player.position.x<41 {
 let up = SKAction.moveByX(0,y: 400, duration: 1.0)
 player.runAction(up)
 }
```

Comment: That is crazy,  just do `if(Int(player.position.x) == 40)`, or use round depending on logic, since 39.1 may not be the same as 40 as far as pixel locations go (I.E.  the coder wants 39.1 to actually go to 39 not 40, thus failing the condition)